# How can i call ScopedModelDescendant in method?

Tags: flutter

Usually, I use "ScopedModelDescendant" with Widgets but Now, 
I want to use in a method. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look following code

```
Widget getDescendantModel() => 
    new ScopedModelDescendant<CounterModel>(
      builder: (context, child, model) => new Text(
          model.counter.toString(),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1),
    );
```